# Vaadin 8: Create forms from Java beans

Tags: forms, vaadin, javabeans, vaadin8

I am looking for a library similar to MetaWidget which can derive an application form from a bean and vice versa for Vaadin 8. MetaWidget is on the state of Vaadin 6 and a little complicated to use.

If there isn't any library then I consider to create one myself but I don't wanted to recreate the wheel.

Comment: This Question is unclear. Vaadin 8 already has a simple yet powerful data-binding facility that is savvy with JavaBeans. How does that not meet your needs? What other features are seeking specifically?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But how about a ready FormLayout with form elements derived from a bean? For simple data types such as strings or integers that should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, Vaadin 8 has built-in data binding supported with the `Binder` class. Especially, the `bindInstanceFields` maybe of interest for you to simplify binding bean properties to field components. Layouting is simplified by `FormLayout`.

However, I am not aware of an add-on or library that automatically picks the right field components and lays them out.

References:

- [Blog: Vaadin 8 Binder](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-8-binder), Section "Declarative Binding"
- [Documentation: Forms](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

This Vaadin add-on may help. It generates CRUD UI from entity beans:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/crud-ui-add-on/